# slick slider not working

Tags: jquery, slider

I want to use slick slider in my blog.  But while I see its js (slick.min.js) file in the blog (I saw by firefox developer tool), the slider is still not working.

inline styles is not my problem. my problem is the functionality of the slider.

I added slick.css too but nothing changed.

my blog address:

[30tizen.rozblog.com](http://30tizen.rozblog.com)

problem in brands holder in bottom

this is slick official web:
http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<body>

<div style="width: 1140px; margin: 0px auto;" class="bx-wrapper">
<div style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; position: relative; height: 71px; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);" class="bx-viewport">

  <ul style=" position: relative; transition-duration: 0.5s;" class="slickslider">

    <li  style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 133.75px; margin-right: 10px;">
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" data-src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/thirrymugler.png" alt="Thierry Mugler" width="134" height="71">
</li>
<li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 133.75px; margin-right: 10px;">
<img class="lazyload" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" data-src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/Lalique.png" alt="Lalique" width="134" height="71">
</li>
<li  style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 133.75px; margin-right: 10px;">
<img src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/yves.png" data-src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/yves.png" alt="yves saint laurent" width="134" height="71">
</li>
<li  style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 133.75px; margin-right: 10px;">
<img src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/dg.png" data-src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/dg.png" alt="Dolce & Gabbana" width="134" height="71">
</li>
<li  style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 133.75px; margin-right: 10px;">
<img  src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/giorgio_armnai.png" data-src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/giorgio_armnai.png" alt="Giorgio Armani" width="134" height="71">
</li>
<li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 133.75px; margin-right: 10px;">
<img src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/Bershka.png?v=1" data-src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/Bershka.png?v=1" alt="Bershka" width="134" height="71">
</li>
<li  style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 133.75px; margin-right: 10px;">
<img  src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/shifer.png?v=1" data-src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/shifer.png?v=1" alt="Shifer" width="134" height="71">
</li>
<li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 133.75px; margin-right: 10px;"><a href="/page/brand/berttonix/?s=60651" targrt="_blank">
<img  src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/berttonix.png" data-src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/berttonix.png" alt="Berttonix" width="134" height="71">
</a>
</li>
<li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 133.75px; margin-right: 10px;">
<img  src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/gucci.png" data-src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/gucci.png" alt="Gucci" width="134" height="71">
</li>
<li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 133.75px; margin-right: 10px;">
<img  src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/versace.png" data-src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/versace.png" alt="Versace" width="134" height="71">
</li>
<li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 133.75px; margin-right: 10px;">
<img  src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/chanel.png" data-src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/chanel.png" alt="Chanel" width="134" height="71">
</li>
<li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 133.75px; margin-right: 10px;">
<img  src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/ck.png" data-src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/ck.png" alt="calvin klein" width="134" height="71">
</li>
<li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 133.75px; margin-right: 10px;">
<img src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/givanchy.png" data-src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/givanchy.png" alt="Givenchy" width="134" height="71">
</li>
<li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 133.75px; margin-right: 10px;">
<img  src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/BVLGARI.png" data-src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/BVLGARI.png" alt="BVLgari" width="134" height="71">
</li>
<li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 133.75px; margin-right: 10px;">
<img  src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/rayban.png" data-src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/rayban.png" alt="ray ban" width="134" height="71">
</li>
<li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 133.75px; margin-right: 10px;">
<img src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/Shiseido.png" data-src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/Shiseido.png" alt="Shiseido" width="134" height="71">
</li>
<li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 133.75px; margin-right: 10px;">
<img src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/Azzaro.png" data-src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/Azzaro.png" alt="Azzaro" width="134" height="71">
</li>
<li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 133.75px; margin-right: 10px;">
<img src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/paccorabbane.png" data-src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/paccorabbane.png" alt="Paco Rabanne" width="134" height="71">
</li>
<li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 133.75px; margin-right: 10px;">
<img src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/desquard.png" data-src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/desquard.png" alt="Dsquared" width="134" height="71">
</li>
<li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 133.75px; margin-right: 10px;">
<img src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/thirrymugler.png" data-src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/thirrymugler.png" alt="Thierry Mugler" width="134" height="71">
</li>
<li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 133.75px; margin-right: 10px;">
<img src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/Lalique.png" data-src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/Lalique.png" alt="Lalique" width="134" height="71">
</li>
<li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 133.75px; margin-right: 10px;">
<img src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/yves.png" data-src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/yves.png" alt="yves saint laurent" width="134" height="71">
</li>
<li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 133.75px; margin-right: 10px;">
<img class="  lazyloaded" src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/dg.png" data-src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/dg.png" alt="Dolce & Gabbana" width="134" height="71">
</li>
<li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 133.75px; margin-right: 10px;">
<img src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/giorgio_armnai.png" data-src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/giorgio_armnai.png" alt="Giorgio Armani" width="134" height="71">
</li>
<li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 133.75px; margin-right: 10px;">
<img src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/Bershka.png?v=1" data-src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/Bershka.png?v=1" alt="Bershka" width="134" height="71">
</li>
<li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 133.75px; margin-right: 10px;">
<img src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/shifer.png?v=1" data-src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/shifer.png?v=1" alt="Shifer" width="134" height="71">
</li>
<li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 133.75px; margin-right: 10px;">
<img src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/berttonix.png" data-src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/berttonix.png" alt="Berttonix" width="134" height="71">
</li>
<li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 133.75px; margin-right: 10px;">
<img src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/gucci.png" data-src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/gucci.png" alt="Gucci" width="134" height="71">
</li>
<li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 133.75px; margin-right: 10px;">
<img src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/versace.png" data-src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/versace.png" alt="Versace" width="134" height="71">
</li>
<li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 133.75px; margin-right: 10px;">
<img  src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/chanel.png" data-src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/chanel.png" alt="Chanel" width="134" height="71">
</li>
<li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 133.75px; margin-right: 10px;">
<img src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/ck.png" data-src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/ck.png" alt="calvin klein" width="134" height="71">
</li>
<li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 133.75px; margin-right: 10px;">
<img src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/givanchy.png" data-src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/givanchy.png" alt="Givenchy" width="134" height="71">
</li>
<li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 133.75px; margin-right: 10px;">
<img  src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/BVLGARI.png" data-src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/BVLGARI.png" alt="BVLgari" width="134" height="71">
</li>
<li  style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 133.75px; margin-right: 10px;">
<img class="  lazyloaded" src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/rayban.png" data-src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/rayban.png" alt="ray ban" width="134" height="71">
</li>
<li style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 133.75px; margin-right: 10px;">
<img src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/Shiseido.png" data-src="http://img.shixon.com/brand/Shiseido.png" alt="Shiseido" width="134" height="71">
 </li>

  </ul>
  
</div>
  
  
  
<script src="http://rozup.ir/view/590908/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://rozup.ir/view/1496235/slick.min.js"></script>
  
  
 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.slickslider').slick({

 autoplay: true,
 infinite: true,
 slidesToShow: 8,
 slidesToScroll: 1,
 Speed: 2000,
 arrows: false,
  
});

});
</script>


</body>
</html> 
</div>
```

I am waiting your answers. Thanks.

Comment: Why you using the inline styles?

Comment: i copied this style from shixon.com ,but i was'nt succsesful in finding what jquery library or package they are useing.  but i find stack slider useful & easy in web.

Comment: I think you didn't add slick.css, it must be linked

Comment: i added slick.css too.but not changed. if we could speak farsi would be better to solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just injected `slick.css` to your site and slick worked fine for me, so add this.

[image]

Also you added `visible-lg` class to the parent of your `slick` (`BrandsHolder`), if you are not familiar with bootstrap. by adding this class, you can see the element only in 992px and above.

Important: I think you should change the HTML, I can see lot of `meta` tags and all `css` files inside `body` tag, it's completely wrong !!!