# Slick Slider is not working on the website?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, slider

I am making a slider using Bootstrap and Slick slider I have added all the Required CDNs But I don't know why it is not working I have searched this on the internet there are many questions on StackOverflow Like [slick slider not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36938644/slick-slider-not-working) and [slick slider not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36938644/slick-slider-not-working) but none of them

```js
$('.testmonials').slick({
    centerMode: true,
    centerPadding: '60px',
    slidesToShow: 3,
    responsive: [
      {
        breakpoint: 768,
        settings: {
          arrows: false,
          centerMode: true,
          centerPadding: '40px',
          slidesToShow: 3
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 480,
        settings: {
          arrows: false,
          centerMode: true,
          centerPadding: '40px',
          slidesToShow: 1
        }
      }
    ]
  });
```

```css
body{
  padding:50px 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  
  
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.7.0/gsap.min.js"
    integrity="sha512-2fk3Q4NXPYAqIha0glLZ2nluueK43aNoxvijPf53+DgL7UW9mkN+uXc1aEmnZdkkZVvtJZltpRt+JqTWc3TS3Q=="
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Carousel.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha512-NWNl2ZLgVBoi6lTcMsHgCQyrZVFnSmcaa3zRv0L3aoGXshwoxkGs3esa9zwQHsChGRL4aLDnJjJJeP6MjPX46Q=="
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.css"
    integrity="sha512-wR4oNhLBHf7smjy0K4oqzdWumd+r5/+6QO/vDda76MW5iug4PT7v86FoEkySIJft3XA0Ae6axhIvHrqwm793Nw=="
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />

  
</head>
<body>
   <!-- Testimonials Slider -->
    <div class="row testmonials">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
            <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
            <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Special title treatment</h5>
            <p class="card-text">With supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>

  <script src="index.js"></script>
  <script src="carousel.js"></script>

  <!-- Jquery CDN -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- Slick Slider CDN -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js"
    integrity="sha512-XtmMtDEcNz2j7ekrtHvOVR4iwwaD6o/FUJe6+Zq+HgcCsk3kj4uSQQR8weQ2QVj1o0Pk6PwYLohm206ZzNfubg=="
    crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    
  <!-- Slick Slider Function -->

  <script src="slicker.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

is helping in my case.
So please Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I see your code is duplicated. JQuery selects all elements with the same class for you, so remove that second and third slicks.

Also, the error is caused by calling 'init' twice. [Error in slick.js: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of null"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35884752/error-in-slick-js-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-add-of-null)

Comment: Could you please Elaborate that Or post it in an answer format

Comment: Yes. The error is caused by you calling slick four times.

Comment: I have removed the Slicks but Still it is not working

Comment: Only This error in my console " Refused to apply style from 'http://127.0.0.1:5500/style.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled. "

Comment: You included jQuery twice. Remove one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236600/discussion-between-shayan-kanwal-and-tom-epsilon).

Answer (score 0):

place your slider init file under slick slider js cdn file, hope it will work